# Changing Fusion Table Card Layouts Programmatically

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables, google-drive-api

While creating a staff database using Fusion Tables and Google Apps Script, I am trying to leverage the existing Fusion Tables UI as much as possible. Cards have been very useful but I am looking for a way that I can programmatically change their layout.

For each entry in the database, a user can upload relevant documents and attach them to an entry. The files are stored in google drive and a link to that document is stored (as an html string) in one of the database fields. Here is a [simple image](https://www.diigo.com/item/image/3toye/g87b?size=o) of what that may look like and the [layout code](https://www.diigo.com/item/image/3toye/dtok?size=o) to make it.

The problem is that the uploadable files (and fields) are dynamic. The user can add or redefine those fields through my ui and I need the full list of available files on each card to adapt accordingly so I don't have to manually configure the layout each time. How can I create a list of links on the card?

Other background info:

- The fusion table will be view only. I haven't figured out a way to validate data entry in the fusion table ui so data entry will be done programmatically and in a custom ui.
- I understand that my current method is not very robust and I am very open to other ways of providing access to these files through the card. I've even toyed with the idea of having a general html field for each entry which is programmatically created to display what I want. I'm just hoping there's a better way.

P.S. I've been struggling with reputation limitations for posting links and images. If you think I'm reputable, please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the uploadable files (and fields) are dynamic. The
>   user can add or redefine those fields through my ui and I need the
>   full list of available files on each card to adapt accordingly so I
>   don't have to manually configure the layout each time. How can I
>   create a list of links on the card?

I may not be exactly following, but it sounds like your app can change the schema for each user? That's what your sample info window HTML seems to show. But that would require a separate table for each app user. If that's not the case then I'm not clear how you are using the term "field".

In any case, the Fusion Tables API does allow you to change template contents, which may solve your problem: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/template

Comment: To clarify, I mean that the user can choose to add another file type to the database. This creates a new column in the fusion table to store the file url. The link you sent looks very useful for maps, but does it also apply for cards?

Comment: So every user can end up adding additional columns? Is this all in a single table? Because that doesn't sound like it's going to scale too well. As for cards, yes, templates are the same for info windows and cards. You just need the relevant template ID, which you can get from the Tools > Publish dialog in  the HTML and JavaScript section.